# Vertical Scaling of Java real-time application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

With GC tuning I am successfully able to get performance for real-time java applications and avoiding recognizable GC pauses. But, this holds good up to ~20 GB of heap space.

Decrease in the hardware cost has made even 100GB of RAM machines affordable. But, still with Java due to GC pauses, higher heap sizes like 50 GB can send you into nightmare at regular times.

I understand that there are options like off-heap and distributed-heap. But, off-heap has a disadvantage of se/derialization and distributed-heap on the hand increases maintenance cost. Further, in distributed-heap you are actually not fully utilizing RAM (say 64 GB) which these days are becoming common as commodity.

Therefore, to fully utilize the potential of RAM, what are the good solutions for vertical scaling of Java applications?

Comment: "Java real-time application" <= lol wut? You really shouldn't use Java for a real time application. It is simply not made for that.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel - that's a pretty narrowminded view of the jvm.  there are jvms which are targeted at real-time applications.

Comment: i assume you are referring to the oracle jvm, which is pretty much targeted at "general purpose".  have you looked at jvms which are specifically designed for huge memory, like azul?

Comment: @jtahlborn - Have heard of Azul's performance. But, am considering only open source solutions.

Comment: Most technologies for scaling java are centered on web applications, which are not typically very memory constrained.  I/O limitations tend to kick in first, hence we usually cluster before throwing massive resources at a single machine.

Comment: The concept of real-time systems is related with the fact that you have some guarantees about the time an operation may take. I do not think that Java should be used for real time applications. What is the underlying operating system? If the OS is not designed for RT applications, then your application is unlikely to be RT.

Comment: What is your GC pause target? In my experience, there is no principal difference between 20 and 50 GiB of heap in HotSpot JVM.

Comment: Alexey, the difference comes from the number of objects, not from the heap size.
try to create a list with 100m Integer objects (raw data size is 100m * 4 = 400m), see what happens with the GC as you are creating the objects (and maintaining references to them of course).

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin - Target is to have GC pauses should be within 200 ms. But with increasing heap size to 50 GB, YoungGen itself is set to 4GB to have YoungGen Collection frequency of at least 2 seconds. But, with this size it normally takes 500+ ms in YoungGen collection which is not acceptable as it is stop-the-world.

Comment: @jtahlborn - It depends on definition of real-time. We are developing battery powered high precision measuring devices collecting data in real-time. We are measuring energy in power grid during some time period (say one hour or one day). Even 3 ms pause is too much for us because we could lost data from one 20 ms period (assuming 50 Hz frequency).

Answer (score 5):

I am working on a primitive collections library called [Banana](https://github.com/omry/banana/). Banana addresses those exact issues.
It supports LinkedLists, HashMaps and possibly other data structures soon without the overhead of keeping N objects. basically - the entire storage can be inside an int[] array (or many).

While I did not yet officially released it, most of it is well tested and I have already ran it successfully on servers with 144GB of RAM, maintaining fast and consistent performance without any GC pauses.

Check out [this](https://github.com/omry/banana/wiki/Long-to-fixed-size-object-benchmark) hash-map benchmark to get an idea on how to use Banana to store data and how well it scales vertically.

https://github.com/omry/banana/wiki/Long-to-fixed-size-object-benchmark

See the [wiki](https://github.com/omry/banana/wiki) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will go through it. Is this free to use or has some license for commercial usage.

Comment: free as in Banana (BSD license).

Comment: I basically want to see it being used, and hopefully get some acknowledgment from users that this is indeed as awesome as I think it is, and possibly also general open source goodness like bug reports and code contributions.

Comment: As I see, it is creating an allocator which basically contains integer array. This seems to be working on for primitives. What if i want to store simple POJOs and how it eases the work of GC then.

Comment: you will have to serialize them into the array (more accurately, find a way to represent them as ints). the scaling problem you are seeing is because with a lot of live objects the GC cycles becomes longer and longer. (try creating 100m Integer objects and see what happens).
the upside is that you can access the data as you need it, without having to deserialize the whole thing.
basically, you need to cut down the number of live Java Objects, so no POJO for you.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection time is a function of the number of live objects in your heap. This means that if your allocation rate is very high but the number of live objects is always low, you can use as much RAM as you want without having significant pauses.

This statement is particularly true with the Troughput Collector (`-XX:+UseParallelOldGC`).

If you use CMS, then you probably want to check its incremental mode (`-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode`). It will trigger smaller CMS cycles to clean a smaller fraction of your heap, while leveraging your hardware and without STW pauses.

If CMS is not an option, then you should have a look at G1 (`-XX:+UseG1GC`), which is a new Garbage Collector designed for large heaps. The principle is : clean only several regions of the heap at each cycle but make sure these regions contains a lot of dead objects (quick gains).

Hope that helps !

Sources :

- http://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All
- http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on scaling heap size of JVM. You can read more details [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html) and [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html).

Main conclusion: young GC pause have two components constant and variable.

Constant component depends on old space size and for 64GiB, I expect it to be 80ms-120ms (dependent on hardware).

Variable component depends on surviving of objects in young space (thus it changes from collection to collection). It is really application specific, but you usually can reduce it by reducing young space (at cost of more frequent pauses).

In your case for 4 GiB of young space you have 500ms. Assuming variable component is 400ms,if you reduce young space to 1 GiB you should have ~200ms pauses (but 2 times per second).

Another approach is to use more CPU cores, young GC paralleling [extremely well](http://blog.ragozin.info/2013/06/java-gc-in-numbers-parallel-young.html).